# form_submit() and form_validate() doesn't work for tableselect

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to create sort of slider that slides the user selected blocks. to do so I need to list all of the blocks and let the user to select them, I used `tableselect`. this is my `MODULE.module`

```
function deckslider_permission() {
return array(
        'administer deckslider' => array(
                'title' => t('Administer deckslider module'),
                'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for Trails module.'),
        ),
);
}

function deckslider_menu() {
$items['admin/config/deckslider'] = array(
        'title' => 'Deck Slider',
        'description' => 'deckslider configuration',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('deckslider_admin_settings'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer deckslider'),
        'file' => 'deckslider.admin.inc',
        'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'deckslider'),
);
return $items;
}

function select_blocks_submit(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
dsm("Hello");
print "Hello";
}

function deckslider_form_select_blocks_alter(){
    $form['#submit'][]='my_submit';
}

function my_submit(){
    dsm("Hello");
    print "d";
}
```

and it is `deckslider.admin.inc`:

```
function deckslider_admin_settings() {
    global $theme;
    $blocks = _block_rehash($theme);
    $header = array(
        'title' => t('Block'), 
    );

    $options = array();
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($blocks) ; $i++){
        $options[] = array('title' => t($blocks[$i]['info']));
    }

    $form['select_blocks'] = array(
        '#type' => "tableselect",
        '#header' => $header,
        '#options' => $options,
        '#multiple' => TRUE,
    );
    return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

The problem is the form has a default `save configuration` button and I can't trigger any function for its submission. this is the output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to change the name of the submit handler so it matches Drupal's naming convention of `FORM_FUNCTION_submit`, e.g.

```
function deckslider_admin_settings_submit(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dsm("Hello");
}
```

Or add the handler manually in your form function:

```
function deckslider_admin_settings($form, &$form_state) {
    global $theme;
    $blocks = _block_rehash($theme);
    $header = array(
        'title' => t('Block'), 
    );

    $options = array();
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($blocks) ; $i++){
        $options[] = array('title' => t($blocks[$i]['info']));
    }

    $form['select_blocks'] = array(
        '#type' => "tableselect",
        '#header' => $header,
        '#options' => $options,
        '#multiple' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = 'select_blocks_submit';

    return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Comment: I used the second option `function select_blocks_submit(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {}` and it reports this warning: `Warning: Missing argument 3 for select_blocks_submit()` what is this?

Comment: The signature for submit/validate functions is `function select_blocks_submit(&$form, &$form_state)`, just remove the third arg